# Can we use redux-toolkit in chrome extension development?

Tags: reactjs, redux, google-chrome-extension

Recently, I have been working on Chrome extension app development with React, Webpack and Nodejs. I have watch a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXem_TaH9To&list=PLBS1L3Ug2VVpgpDEcLmapOk52mVGv4MIu&index=12&t=53s which says redux is not allowed to add into chrome extension app. Does it includes redux-toolkit? Is there alternatives to redux?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, Redux Toolkit can be used in Chrome  development.

Comment: And can chrome extension app with redux toolkit package published to chrome web store?